# Deep Learning: Use L2 and Dropout Regularization Simultaneously?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, ridge-regression, dropout

Is there a theoretical basis against using both L2 and Dropout regularization simultaneously for training a deep neural network?  They are both related but could they be complementary if used together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The paper {1} that introduced dropout combined dropout with L2:

> We found that dropout combined with max-norm regularization gives the
>   lowest generalization error.

[image]

---

- {1} Srivastava, Nitish, Geoffrey E. Hinton, Alex Krizhevsky, Ilya Sutskever, and Ruslan Salakhutdinov. "Dropout: a simple way to prevent neural networks from overfitting." Journal of Machine Learning Research 15, no. 1 (2014): 1929-1958. http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a.old/srivastava14a.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference in the original paper!  Sometimes it is best to go to the source.  As a follow up, would there be an issue with using dropout + l2 + maxnorm simulteously?

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore

Comment: @MayurKulkarni Stack Exchange should take care of dead links, not individual users.